# Specific use of data about users

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Ahoy,

I would like to create a simple commercial web application that would analyze traffic on the fan page. Is it acceptable to generate a list of the most active users along with their first and last name? Of course, this data would come from the Facebook Graph.

I have already read the Facebook Platform Policies and I'm still not sure :(

Best,
BA

Comment: "Acceptable" is a very subjective term and not really on-topic for Stack Overflow, sorry.  If you want to know if you are potentially violating Facebook's terms of service, you should ask Facebook.  If you want to know if you're violating any legal statute, you should ask an attorney.  If you want to know if you're violating any moral or ethical standard, you should ask... well... that's up to you I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Here in Portugal I've seen a lot of big registered marks doing that, but usually they do retrieve "names" of people through an application that someone explicits that allows those data to be used in the future.

According to Facebook Rules, once users insert their data in their platform, it can be used by the system, and once you are using the system... you could be using the data?

It is a kind of a controversial discussion.

In the part of Facebook I think you can get a Yes. In the part of really be legal to do that, you should ask a lawyer about your country laws.